# Hide/locking a <form> button until form is completely filled with validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, disable-link

I make my JSON script with a form and a button, but when I demo it on someone, they can press the **submit** button whenever they like. Here is my code:

```html
<form action="action_page.php" method="GET">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"<br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"<br><br>
</form>
```

All I need now is validation and how to lock or hide the button. 
I tried using `<script>` with `function` and `getElementById` but I simply do not know how to lock it. Here is the message that will be inputted when it is locked and the form isn't completed:

> You have not finished the information input for the survey. Please
> input "*Your First Name*" and "*Your Last Name*" to enter the survey.

When they finish, I will input a loading icon until fully loaded.

---

#### Code Language(s)

I use fiddles to make my code, so I use:

- HTML
- JSON
- Pinch of jQuery (loading icon)

  ---

#### Answer Expectations

In my answers, I need:

- Recommended Code Language
- Code for note purposes
- Crossed out attributes
- Attributes before coding explanations

---

**EDIT:** I just noticed that I can use the `disabled` boolean attribute [here,](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) so all I need is validation to disable the boolean attribute so they can press the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I recommend JavaScript but it is not secure at all. However its the most effective in this case. Here is the code: (Note that i changed the html too)

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="get" >
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onkeyup="inputEntries()"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" onkeyup="inputEntries()"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" disabled="true">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  var fname_var = document.getElementById("fname");
  var lname_var = document.getElementById("lname");

  var submit_btn_var = document.getElementById("submit_btn");

  function inputEntries(){
    if(lname_var.value != "" && fname_var.value != "")
        submit_btn_var.disabled = false;
    else
      submit_btn_var.disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

What it does is that if both input fields are empty the button is not clickable but if both are it can be clicked. hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either pure javascript or jQuery to validate.

In the below code you would see we are first binding a change event to the input field and getting its values. If both values are present, the disabled attribute of the submit button is removed. Else the opposite.

```
<p id="msg">You have not finished the information input for the survey. Please input "*Your First Name*" and "*Your
Last Name*" to enter the survey.</p>

<form action="action_page.php" method="GET">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"<br><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"<br><br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
  ('#btn-submit').prop('disabled', true);

  $("input[type=text]").change(function(){
    if ($('#fname').val() && $('#lname').val()) {
      $('#btn-submit').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#msg').hide();
    } else {
      $('#btn-submit').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#msg').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-kgzhuo?file=index.html